# How to compute loudness from audio signal?

Tags: python, signal-processing, audio-processing

I have an audio signal and I want to detect loud moments from it.

The problem I have is that I am not sure if the algorithm / code I present bellow are correct or not.

I read on many posts that the concept of "loudness" is complex and depends on individuals. I also read that it could be somehow approximated using spectrogram, A-weighting and RMS. I'm a novice at audio processing, but based on what I've read, I wrote the following algorithm:

- Compute the spectrogram using STFT
- Convert it to dB
- Apply A-weighting
- Compute RMS

The corresponding code I've written using Librosa is:

```py
# Load the input audio
y, sr = librosa.load(path, sr=22050)

# Compute the spectrogram (magnitude)
n_fft = 2048
hop_length = 1024
spec_mag = abs(librosa.stft(y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length))

# Convert the spectrogram into dB
spec_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spec_mag)

# Compute A-weighting values
freqs = librosa.fft_frequencies(sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft)
a_weights = librosa.A_weighting(freqs)
a_weights = np.expand_dims(a_weights, axis=1)

# Apply the A-weghting to the spectrogram in dB
spec_dba = spec_db + a_weights

# Compute the "loudness" value
loudness = librosa.feature.rms(S=librosa.db_to_amplitude(spec_dba))
```

Am I on a good track?
Is this algorithm correct?
Am I using Librosa correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with the results you are getting? If not, this might not be the correct forum to ask this rather open ended multi-question of yours.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear. My main problem is to know if the algorithm I'm using is correct and makes sense. I have results that could be considered good, but maybe I'm applying the weights not correctly (addition instead of multiplication) and this could lead to serious detection problems. I'll reformulate the question.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think you can only compare your signal level with other values and get a relative amplification (+dB) or attenuation (-dB). To get the loudness, you must have some reference point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @VPfB. I can define a reference value when converting the amplitude to dB: `librosa.amplitude_to_db(spec_mag, ref=np.max)`. By doing so, the output curve only differs from a scale perspective (same shape different scale).

Comment: If you care about a careful, standard definition of loudness, then yes, that is a deep topic. Have a look at something like [Rec. ITU-R BS.1771-1 "Requirements for loudness and true-peak indicating meters"](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bs/R-REC-BS.1771-1-201201-I!!PDF-E.pdf) or ["Evaluation of Objective Loudness Meters" by Gilbert Soulodre](http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=12790). If you are just informally looking for "when is this signal loud", then computing RMS under a sliding window is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you @PascalGetreuer for the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know your programming language but the concept seems almost right.

though you do not need to convert to db because of the a-weighting, as the usual a-weighting function is for linear 0-1 already.

for LUFS the usual way is as follows:

for each channel individually,

- apply the k-filter (fft followed by a-weighting, but there are also simpler implementations using HP/LP filters)
- mean square
- in the case of prologic or immersive audio formats: you might also need to substract a few db from the rear and ceiling speakers, for example -1.5 db for the rears in 5.1
- sum channels
- 10log10

this is for history/realtime.

then for LUFS you´d do:

- integrate the results (accumulate values over the whole track, while leaving out moments which are below -60db)
- in the case of prologic: the LFE channel is not part of the game, you completely ignore it.

Comment: Librosa's A-weighting function seems to give the weights in dB (see librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.A_weighting.html). That's why I converted to dB. Maybe I got that wrong?

Comment: no, it can be that there are formulas which are using db already.

Comment: on wikipedia they split it up, the weighting is linear and really simple, the lower formula is for the db conversion.

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/8b3040c49545452a0c6eec52e4a2eee38483a540

since they mostly use FFT, linear is good to have.

Comment: but i´d like to add one more thing or maybe even have correct what i said above.
far more common than using a noise gate before the power measurement is to measure the LUFS of everyhting, and then not include all LUFS values below -23 dbFS when accumulating them to find the overall LUFS of a piece of music.

Answer (score 0):

You can try PyDub library. Gives you Volume in DB.